# Multiple filter condition for AngularJS - Javascript

Tags: angularjs

We have been using AngularJS filter many times as shown below:

```
$filter('filter')(vm.listEmployee, { FieldId: id })
```

However, what if we need to add one more condition with 'And' or 'Or' operator?

So, far I managed to do it like

```
$filter('filter')($filter('filter')(vm.FieldsControls, { FieldId: id }), {City:city})
```

Is there any better way to achieve this using the same inline format?

Comment: Further, how can I use not equal to operator in this format? e.g. it is FieldId: id i.e. FieldId == id, however, what format should we use if we want to negate this condition.

Comment: Instead of adding comments to your post, you should just [edit] your question to include the extra clarifications.  Comments are temporary discussion points.

Answer (score 0):

If you chain the base filter of angular you will apply an AND

This basic filter given by angular will perform equality.

If you want something more complex you can implement your own filter.

You could declare a custom filter in your controller that take the values and a expression as parameters and call $scope.$eval on them to perform complex conditions.